# how to realize edge detection of grayscale image using Cellular automaton in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to use the cellular model for edge detection in an image is grayscale using Netlogo
but my problem is how can I calculate the differance between pea calculate and neighborhood using netlogo

Comment: What is pea and what is neighborhood? Can you provide some examples to help us put your question into context?

Comment: pea i mean point and neighborhood reports an agentset containing the 8 surrounding patches (neighbors) or 4 surrounding patches (neighbors4).

Comment: 22|10|3
24|25|2
20|23|10 
if i have this exm my point is 25 and her neighbors 4 is 10 ,2, 23,24 i went to calculate the different between 25 and each neighbors

Comment: Is a point an xcor ycor? or a numerical value representing the color? Is 10,2,23, and 24 who values? or pcolor values?

Comment: the image can viewed as a particular configuration for a cellular automaton whose cellular space is the two dimensional array defined by the image. Each site in the table corresponds to a pixel.
The edge detection of the model is based on a two-dimensional cellular automaton A (S, N, μ) with S = {0, ., K-1} is the set of states corresponding gray level values of pixels of the image. N is a neighborhood of Von Neumann (neighbors4)) μ is the local transition function defined as
µ(s1,s2, s,s3, s4)= 0,if   ⃒s- s i |< Ԑ  for i Є {1..4}
else  s,but my problem is how can i calculate  ⃒s- s i |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your formula, you want to know for a particular point in an image the absolute difference between two adjacent pixels |s-si| for i in [1...4].

Assuming you've read the image in and stored them into the patches and the patches pcolor is the corresponding color in the image.

Then

```
ask patches
[
   let s pcolor
   let all-si [abs (s - pcolor) ] of neighbors4
]
```

In your example if you have a patch with pcolor 2 and the neighbors in the north south east and west directions are 1,2,3,4 respectively, then all-si will be a list of [1,0,1,2] in a random order.

I'm still unsure of how you define the edge, but this will help you to get what was asked in the comments.

Comment: `neighbors4` is always in random order, so you'll get those numbers, but not necessarily in that order.